# Can we create MS Word table inline with the surrounding text

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

Is the following possible in MS Word:[image]
I am using `MS Word 2010` and tried the different options described in [step 2 here](http://www.bettersolutions.com/word/WAA743/LI220121911.htm). But still did not get the above. Could someone define the options in the dialog box shown in the above link that would make it work; or is it even possible?